react-oidc-context updates scripts and requests when call /authorize
I use react, react-oidc-context. I configured oidcConfig, added it to AuthProvider and everything works, but I see that it takes me 5 minutes to load all the scripts and requests. It doesn't have to be like this for me. I also noticed a strange prefix VMXXXXX in the initiator column in devtools, this can be seen in the screenshot. What could all this mean?
screenshot 1
screenshot 2
I don't know why this is happening
